# DateTime Formatting in Visualforcepage (Comment Section)

Tags: visualforce, datetime

I am now creating a comment section on my visualforce page and I don't know how to achieve this kind of datetime formatting.

[image]

This is my code in Visualforce page.

```
<div class="commentDate">

 <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' @ 'hh:mm a}">                                                   
          <apex:param value="{!comment.CreatedDate}"/>                                                    
  </apex:outputText>

 </div>
```

By the way the comment.CreatedDate is a DateTime

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve what you need via some logic:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(date = TODAY(), 'Today', IF(date = TODAY() -1, 'Yesterday', {0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy'}))} @ {0,date, hh:mm a}">                                                   
      <apex:param value="{!comment.CreatedDate}"/>                                                    
</apex:outputText>
```

If something like that doesn't work, you can create 3 seperate blocks and render them seperately:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!date = TODAY()}" value="">
<apex:outputText rendered="{!date = TODAY()-1}" value="">
<apex:outputText rendered="{!AND(date != TODAY(), date != TODAY()-1)}" value="">
```

### Update:

In playing around I ran into a problem where my "date" field was actually a "date-time" field which for some reason or another (probably on the scale of milliseconds) wouldn't work properly. I converted these fields using `DATEVALUE(date)` into a date field and used it with the `TODAY()` method which worked. Here's some code that you can use to prove that my second method works;

Controller:

```
public DateTime todayTest {get; set;}
public DateTime yesterdayTest {get; set;}
public DateTime lastweekTest {get; set;}

public testPageController () {
    this.todayTest = system.now();
    this.yesterdayTest = system.now().addDays(-1);
    this.lastweekTest = system.now().addDays(-7);
}
```

Visualforce

```
{!DATEVALUE(todayTest)} - {!TODAY()} - {!DATEVALUE(todayTest) = TODAY()}<br/>
{!DATEVALUE(yesterdayTest)} - {!TODAY()-1} - {!DATEVALUE(yesterdayTest) = TODAY()-1}<br/>
{!lastWeekTest}<br/>

<apex:outputText rendered="{!DATEVALUE(todayTest) = TODAY()}" value="1"/>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!DATEVALUE(yesterdayTest) = TODAY()-1}" value="2"/>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!AND(DATEVALUE(lastweekTest) != TODAY(), DATEVALUE(lastweekTest) != TODAY()-1)}" value="3"/>
```

Here you can clearly see that each value is rendered (123) which shows that the attributes will work as expected. You'll just need to update the values to display what you want displayed.

Comment: it's not working. huhuhu

Comment: The problem I have with that is that you said "it's" not working, I gave you two options, which "It" isn't working? "Isn't working" also tells me nothing about your situation, what is it actually doing?

Comment: Thank you @gNerb for your suggestions but they're both not working on my side. Maybe you can help me on this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229738/pass-the-param-to-the-controller-and-return-a-new-value-to-vf-page

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that approach at all as it makes s server call which is terrible inefficient. I'm so incredibly confident that my second approach posted here will work that I'll go prove it out, give me a few.

Comment: @MikeDeVilla Updated my answer